# Map vs Filter over infinite lists?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and i've run into something i can't understand and i can't find an explanation. So, I was testing some functions over infinite lists to see how they worked, and i found a diference between map and filter that I'd like to understand.

`Prelude.map` definition:

```
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

`Prelude.filter` definition:

```
filter _pred []    = []
filter pred (x:xs)
  | pred x         = x : filter pred xs
  | otherwise      = filter pred xs
```

If I run this:

```
map (==5) [1..]
```

The output starts and it never ends, until i stop it. Wich makes sense since the list is infinite.

But now if i run this:

```
filter (==5) [1..]
```

I see nothing, not even `[5,`.
Which also makes sense since the list is infinite too, but i want to understand what's the difference beetwen map and filter that makes this.
Thank you and sorry for my english!

Edit: I was using tryhaskell.org and that was the problem!

Comment: Surely you see `[5` and then nothing?

Comment: i just edited, i dont even see that [5

Comment: Not reproducible on my end. I see the `[5`.

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense. Which compiler/interpreter are you using?

Comment: maybe it's cause I'm using http://tryhaskell.org/. I'll download Haskell plataform and try there!

Comment: Ah - maybe it's waiting for the program to terminate before sending you its output.

Comment: yep, that was it, I'll never trust tryhaskell again! haha
should i leave the question or delete it?

Comment: You might as well leave the question in case someone has the same problem in the future.

Comment: @DemianArdus Please edit it to say you're using tryhaskell.org, which makes it answerable.

Comment: When I type that into tryhaskell.org, I get `:: (Enum a, Eq a, Num a) => [a]`. Very odd

Comment: @Marcin The type signature's odd? Enum and Eq aren't superclasses of Num any more.

Comment: @AndrewC I mean it's odd in that it's at variance with what OP and other commentators report.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, I get that too, but that's because it always prints the type of the expression on the line under the output; the odd thing is that the output which should precede it is absent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discovered in the comments, this is due to using [Try Haskell](http://www.tryhaskell.org/). From experimentation, it appears that it will wait for the program to terminate, 3 seconds to elapse, or 1024 characters of output to be produced, before ending and sending you the result. Unfortunately, `filter (==5) [1..]` will only produce a measly two characters (`[5`), not meeting the 1024 character limit, and for some reason or another Try Haskell won't send `[5` back to you. Running it in a real GHCi should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Its related to the [buffer settings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:12). When you compile it, the BufferMode of *stdin* and *stdout* is by default often set to LineBuffering, printing only on a newline, buffer overflow or manual flush.

GHCi's BufferMode is set to NoBuffering¹, which will print your result immediately.

In case of LineBuffering:

- `map (==5) [1..]` prints its result, because its large output leads to lots of buffer overflows.
- `filter (==5) [1..]` never fills the buffer or writes a newline. So its not printed.

¹ if possible. [NoBuffering for stdin might not work on Windows cmd, when compiled with GHC.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2189)